# Process of developing a custom widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am learning Android app development using Dart/Flutter and I am trying to understand the general process of developing a custom widget for an app. For example, if I need a widget that has a TextField, an Image, and a checkbox, how do I test that widget individually?

I mean, there is no app to put that widget in as of now, so how do I "execute" it to see if that widget is getting laid out correctly and working properly as expected?

In the Java Swing world, I would just put a main method in my component class. In that main method, I would create a frame or something and add that component to that frame. Then run that class directly. That way, I can basically fine tune the component without worrying about running the actual application, and without having to go through the whole app flow to reach that component and check how it looks.

Is it similar in Flutter app as well? Create a dummy app with the widget as the only "screen" and then execute that dummy app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent online tool called "Dart Pad", the link [here](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id) should get you started on basic boilerplate code that is the beginnings of your app.

You can then proceed to create a custom widget, I'll try and replicate your example widget below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
      const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
        MaterialState.pressed,
        MaterialState.hovered,
        MaterialState.focused,
      };
      if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
        return Colors.blue;
      }
      return Colors.red;
    }

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network("https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png"),
          TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Type something")),
          Checkbox(
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(
                () {
                  isChecked = value!;
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dart Pad may not like images from the network in my example, but it's a great way to test your custom widgets quickly if you don't want the hassle of setting up a project space.

Comment: Thank you! and all of the above code should reside in which file? MyStatefulWidget.dart?
Or may be split into two files - the first part in say dummyapp.dar and the second part where the widget is being defined in MyStatefulWidget.dart?

Where should these files be created? In a separate space /folder (unrelated to the main android studio project) or may be in the same project but instead of working on them through Android Studio, use Dartpad to test and finetune. Once done, open them through Android studio and use as a package/library.

Comment: Yea, you can, and it is good practice. As you can see, sometimes adding a lot of sub-widgets and decorating them to look nice can add a lot of code to your page. It would be best to put a widget in a separate file like "MyStatefulWidget.dart". 

You can use android studio for your app development environment. Dart pad should only be used for quick construction of widgets, and you would do main development in an IDE. Then, I copy-paste the widget into my project in android studio/ VSCode when I'm satisfied with how it looks and develop it further from there.

Comment: I would also look at NetNinja for some basic tutorials for flutter, feel free to use any there's a lot of resources to learn flutter on youtube.

Can go to Reso Coder for more advanced lessons on widgets.